# 2D Grid based Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking to make a Grid based movement system like in this photo.

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYIHL.jpg)

I looked for dozens of tutorials but none of them shows a tutorial on how to do it like this, only with a global map range or arrow keys.

The idea is simple click a unit then a `x` by `x` white grid lights up those are spaces you can move on. Then if you click one of the light up tiles you will move to that tile. Then `x` is configurable per "character".

Comment: So what are you having problems with? Is it just trying to work out which grid references to light up given a current position and a value for `x`?

Comment: The problem i am having is how i put it in a "range" i got it to work to move it to the tile i click on only the range is full map. any ideas on how to put a range limiter in the script? and i have problems with lighting up the tiles